Donde mostar la carpeta dist despues de compilar vue3 con vite
Estoy llevando unos ejercicios en vue3 con vite, solo creo la plantilla por defecto que me genera el proyecto, utilizo los siguientes comandos:.
npm init vue@latest

npm install

npm run dev

hasta aqui todo perfecto, hago unas pequeñas modificaciones a los archivos app.vue y de los componentes, luego quiero crear mi compilacion con el siguiente comando:
npm run build 

npm run preview

me genera la carpeta dist con los siguientes archivos:
 vite v4.3.9 building for production...

✓ 44 modules transformed.

dist/assets/logo-277e0e97.svg        0.28 kB │ gzip:  0.20 kB

dist/index.html                      0.42 kB │ gzip:  0.28 kB

dist/assets/AboutView-4d995ba2.css   0.09 kB │ gzip:  0.10 kB

dist/assets/index-efcb3133.css       4.20 kB │ gzip:  1.30 kB

dist/assets/AboutView-52933a18.js    0.23 kB │ gzip:  0.20 kB

dist/assets/index-4c0ba773.js       85.37 kB │ gzip: 33.61 kB

✓ built in 641ms

Ahora segun esta carpeta dist es la que debo usar para montar en el servidor, tengo un servidor local con Wampserver y monto esta carpeta dist en www, y al ejecutar http://localhost/dist/ me muestra una pagina en blanco totalmente.
Agradeceria cualquier ayuda, y de antemano muchas gracias.

Cuando ingresas a la dirección de tu localhost qué error te muestra la consola? a partir de ahí podríamos llegar a la resolución del problema
